Multiple Conditions in Excel considering the table2
I have a data set contains city names.
Table1:

Table2:

I want to apply the Table2 condition .
Exclude USA means "<>USA"
I can do it without considering the Table2 by taking the values manually as below the formula
IF(AND(A2="USA",B2="USA")="INTERNAL",IF(AND(A2<>"USA",B2="USA") = "EXT-IMPORT",""))

If the condition changes I have to edit the formula again. How can I do it by considering the Table2.
Thank you.

It depends significantly on what needs to be able to change. In the example, everything is being compared to just the USA. Do the conditions just need to be able to be changed to a different country, with still only 4 conditions in the table? Or do you need to compare multiple specific countries at a time with more than 4 conditions needed? Do the output values remain the same, or do they need to change as well? Can you give an example of what a changed condition looks like, so we understand exactly what changes can happen?

@Michael Instead of USA If changed to SPE then again I need to edit the formula. Ex. conditions will be SPE, Exclude SPE. output values are same. If conditions are changing again I have edit the formula manually. Hope you got my point.

=SWITCH(CONCAT(N(Table2[@[City1]:[City2]]="USA")),"11","Internal","01","Ext-Import","10","Int-Export","00","External")


Another alternative using XLOOKUP() applying with the use of Table2 conditions so that it becomes dynamic no hardcoding, one can change the conditions in the Table2 to change effect immediately:


=XLOOKUP(
--(A2="USA")&--(B2="USA"),
--(Table2[Cond_1]="USA")&--(Table2[Cond_2]="USA"),
Table2[Output])



Since you also tagged this with Power Query I provide this PQ solution.
Assumption: Table2 will always have four entries and be in the given order that you show in your question. If that is not the case, you will need to supply more information as to the variations
If you want to change city/country, you just need to change Table 2. Of course, you could hard-code the variations into the query.
Table_1 Query
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_1"]}[Content],
    Table2 = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table_2"]}[Content],
    
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"City1", type text}, {"City2", type text}}),
    #"Referral City" = Table2[Cond_1]{0},
    #"Output Column" = Table2[output],

//add column assuming output order unchanged for any Table_2
    #"Add Output" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type","output", (r)=>
        let 
            comp = {r[City1]=#"Referral City",r[City2]=#"Referral City"},
            patterns = {{true,true}, {true,false},{false,true},{false,false}},
            pos = List.PositionOf(patterns,comp)
        in 
            #"Output Column"{pos}, type text)
    
in
    #"Add Output"



You can try this in cell
C2
=LET(_ip,IF(A2<>"USA","Exclude USA",A2)&IF(B2<>"USA","Exclude USA",B2),_op,TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN({"",",","#"},,$F$2:$H$5),",","#"),VLOOKUP(_ip,_op,2,0))


Since the only part that needs to change is the one country, you can construct a formula that references a single cell. Here, I place the reference country in C1 instead of "Result" as a heading, but you can place it anywhere. Here's the formula to place in C2. Note the fixed references on $C$1 so I can fill the formula down.
=IF(A2=$C$1,IF(B2=$C$1,"Internal","Int-Export"),IF(B2=$C$1,"Ext-Import","External"))


Simply changing the one reference cell updates the results for the country entered:

The formula above lets you put the reference cell anywhere you want. However, if you're happy with using the column headings to hold the country, then you could use mixed references in the formula that allow you to enter the formula once in C2, and then drag right as well as drag down, to display for multiple countries at once:
=IF($A2=C$1,IF($B2=C$1,"Internal","Int-Export"),IF($B2=C$1,"Ext-Import","External"))


